# Объясните как правильно работает и как правильно написать конвектор в room? java

Tags: java, sql, android-room

Когда происходит сборка кода, то room выдает ошибку, что не может понять некоторые типы данных и просит их конвертировать. Как правильно нужно сделать конвекцию, чтобы room понимал данные?

К примеру

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "Birthday")
String Birthday;
```

Но приходит ошибка, по типу:

```
param:birthday -> matched field:unmatched
```

Полная ошибка выглядит так:

```
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public class Worker {
       ^
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
  Worker(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,
java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> [param:fname -> matched field:fname, param:lname -> matched field:lname, param:birthday -> matched field:unmatched, param:specName -> matched field:unmatched, param:specId -> matched field:unmatched, param:avatarUrl -> matched field:unmatched]
```

Update: Прочитал по больше статей, предполагаю, что ошибка может быть в конструкторе класса, но все типы данных я проверил и они введены корректно.
Для большого анализа:

```
public class Worker {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "LName")
    String lname;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "FName")
    String fname;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Birthday")
    String Birthday;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "SpecName")
    String SpecName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "SpecID")
    String SpecId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "AvatarURL")
    String AvatarUrl;
    @Ignore
    String Age;

    public Worker(String fname, String lname, String birthday, String specName, String specId, String avatarUrl) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.Birthday = birthday;
        this.SpecName = specName;
        this.SpecId = specId;
        this.AvatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я пока не могу писать комментарии. Попробуйте объявить ваши поля `public`.
Без модификатора, они packaje private и возможно Room не видит их. Или определите public геттеры и сеттеры. Думаю в этом проблема.

Ну и сразу второй вариант. Либо уберите конструктор, либо сделайте чтобы имена переменных в конструкторе, точно совпадали с именами в таблице